# Why does macdeployqt give the error "can't open input file"?

Tags: macos, qt

When I run `macdeployqt` on my .app, it adds the libraries ok, but then makes the application crash when you try to start it. This works fine on Mac OS X 10.7, but on Mac OS X 10.8 DP3 no joy. To install Qt I've used `port install qt4-mac` (however, I may have a much older version of Qt on my 10.7 machine from the Qt website).

Command: `macdeployqt bin/Synergy.app -verbose=3`

Enite log: http://pastebin.com/i37vadB7

```
Log: Using install_name_tool: 
Log:  in "bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib" 
Log:  change reference "/opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib" 
Log:  to "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libz.1.dylib" 
ERROR: "install_name_tool: can't open input file: bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib for writing (Permission denied)
install_name_tool: can't lseek to offset: 0 in file: bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib for writing (Bad file descriptor)
install_name_tool: can't write new headers in file: bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (Bad file descriptor)
install_name_tool: can't close written on input file: bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (Bad file descriptor)
" 
ERROR: "" 
Log: 
Log: Deploying plugins from "/opt/local/plugins" 
Log: Created configuration file: "bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Resources/qt.conf" 
Log: This file sets the plugin search path to "bin/Synergy.app/Contents/PlugIns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading to an old Qt SDK .dmg I had hanging around (qt-sdk-mac-opensource-2010.03.dmg). I also ran `sudo port uninstall qt4-mac` to remove the new SDK.

So looks like the newest version of Qt has a broken `macdeployqt` app.

So here's the Qt version I have now, which works:

```
$ qmake -version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.6.3 in /Library/Frameworks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a privilege issue in macdeployqt.
I solved by using sudo:

```
sudo -s -- 'macdeployqt myapp.app; chown -R $(USER) myapp.app'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it seems that the libcrypto that you are using is linked to libz on the local file system. What you need to do is make sure there is a copy of libz in the Frameworks directory of your bundle and then use `install_name_tool` to change the path to the version in the bundle.

```
install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libz.1.dylib bin/Synergy.app/Contents/Frameworks//libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

If your binary is linked to missing libraries it usually results in a crash.

There have been some issues with `macdeployqt` changing over the last few releases of Qt so you do have to check linked paths.